# Hide keypad with button

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I am using the decimal keypad for some user inputs. With this keypad I can't use the "Done" key for dismissing the keypad, so I have made a button to hide it, it is working fine.

My 1st question is, how can I make this button only appear when the keyboard appears"

My 2nd question (sorry I am very new to Xcode!)
Once the user has inputed the correct values in the 6 textFields, I have to add some calculations and display the results in a separate textField, say for e.g:
textField1 * textField2 / textField3 + textField4 * 150 =......

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, thank you.

Ian.

This is from my .m file (the (IBAction) done) is my button:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

[textField1 resignFirstResponder];
[textField2 resignFirstResponder];
[textField3 resignFirstResponder];
[textField4 resignFirstResponder];
[textField5 resignFirstResponder];
[textField6 resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber1:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber2:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber3:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber4:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber5:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)textFieldNumber6:(id)sender {
}
```

And this is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface benoViewController : UIViewController

{
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField4;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField5;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField6;
}
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber3:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber4:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber5:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldNumber6:(id)sender;
```

@end

Comment: I recommend you to use a `NSArray` to store your text fields. Google `IBOutletCollection` and use one `IBAction` method for all the textfields.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self.textFielX endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry I can't get this to work, I am very new, where exactly do I put this and does it replace anything? I'm using Xcode 5 and just get errors wherever I put this. Thanks.